# Start service in another package without Intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Is there a way to start an Android Service defined in another package without using the Intent-Filter tag in the manifest file? For some reason I would not be able to update the manifest file of the app that contains the Service.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact package name and service name you can create an Intent with that. The service still needs to be declared in the other manifest though.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.otherapplication", "com.example.otherapplication.ServiceName");
startService(intent);
```

Comment: I had tried this approach but it didn't work. Does it require any manifest changes in the target app?

Comment: The other service needs to be declared in it's own manifest or Android will refuse to run it. This just lets you target a service with no other intent filters.

Comment: Yes the service already exists in the app's manifest. Its just that it doesn't have an intent filter on it. And I was unable to get it working with this approach :(

Comment: If the service exists in the other app's manifest, but doesn't have an intent filter then that service is, by definition, private. You cannot start it explicitly from another application unless the manifest definition for the service contains either an intent filter or `android:exported="true"`

Comment: Very good point. See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#exported