# Android 5.0 (Lollipop) startService without import class

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to start from an android widget a service using android > 5.0, but this service is implemented into another project.

If I use a device, with android < 4.4 this code work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.service.example");
startService(intent);
```

I read this post:
[Service Must be explicit: Intent](http://Service%20Intent%20must%20be%20explicit:%20Intent)

and the solution, should be:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

So, how do I start service (using intent) without importing the service class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827703/how-to-make-an-implicit-intent-explicit/35827786#35827786

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start service in another package without Intent filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603381/start-service-in-another-package-without-intent-filter)

Comment: It is similar but not duplicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to actually `setComponent` to start a service in another application. For instance,

**Activity in com.xyz.app1:**

```
Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent();
String pkg = "com.xyz.app2";
String cls = "com.xyz.app2.MyService";
mServiceIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
startService(mServiceIntent);
```

You don't need to set ACTION or CATEGORY if you are specifying a specific component. Make sure that your service is properly defined in the manifest.

Comment: I'll try this method

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It's ok!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the component name:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_ACTION_HERE);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("your.package.name",
                "your.package.name.YourService"));
statService(intent);
```

Comment: This solution is similar to previous one. Thank you! @francesc